# Inversion of a bit

Tags: common-lisp, bit, logical-operators

I haven't been able to find a common-lisp function (or macro) that simply inverts a bit. There are functions that operate on bit arrays, and logical functions that operate on numbers, but these would seem to involve extra steps for inversion of a single bit variable. A tentative solution is

```
(define-modify-macro invertf (&rest args)
  (lambda (bit)
    (if (= bit 0) 1 0)))
```

which works, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant or simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of operators for bitwise arithmetic:

For example you can use

```
(logxor bit 1)
```

This will give you `0` if the bit is 1 and `1` if the bit is 0:

```
(logxor 0 1) ; => 1
(logxor 1 1) ; => 0
```

Of course you can put the `bit` part as the second argument:

```
(logxor 1 bit)
```

**Bonus**:

Perhaps you can make a function and optimise it with a type declaration:

```
(defun invert (bit)
  "Inverts a bit"
  (declare (type bit bit))
  (logxor bit 1))
```

After running `(disassemble 'invert)` I got the following results on SBCL:

**WITHOUT type declaration:**

```
; disassembly for INVERT
; Size: 56 bytes. Origin: #x10059E97FC
; 7FC:       498B4C2460       MOV RCX, [R12+96]               ; thread.binding-stack-pointer
                                                              ; no-arg-parsing entry point
; 801:       48894DF8         MOV [RBP-8], RCX
; 805:       BF02000000       MOV EDI, 2
; 80A:       488BD3           MOV RDX, RBX
; 80D:       4883EC18         SUB RSP, 24
; 811:       48896C2408       MOV [RSP+8], RBP
; 816:       488D6C2408       LEA RBP, [RSP+8]
; 81B:       B904000000       MOV ECX, 4
; 820:       FF1425980B1020   CALL QWORD PTR [#x20100B98]     ; TWO-ARG-XOR
; 827:       488B5DF0         MOV RBX, [RBP-16]
; 82B:       488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP
; 82E:       F8               CLC
; 82F:       5D               POP RBP
; 830:       C3               RET
; 831:       0F0B10           BREAK 16                        ; Invalid argument count trap
```

**WITH type declaration**

```
; disassembly for INVERT
; Size: 25 bytes. Origin: #x1005767CA9
; A9:       498B4C2460       MOV RCX, [R12+96]                ; thread.binding-stack-pointer
                                                          ; no-arg-parsing entry point
; AE:       48894DF8         MOV [RBP-8], RCX
; B2:       488BD3           MOV RDX, RBX
; B5:       4883F202         XOR RDX, 2
; B9:       488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP
; BC:       F8               CLC
; BD:       5D               POP RBP
; BE:       C3               RET
; BF:       0F0B10           BREAK 16                         ; Invalid argument count trap
```

It seems to me that the type declaration saved a few operations.

Let's measure the difference:

```
(defun invert (bit)
  "Inverts a bit"
  (declare (type bit bit))
  (logxor bit 1))

(defun invert-no-dec (bit)
  "Inverts a bit"
  (logxor bit 1))
```

Now running:

```
(time (loop repeat 1000000 do (invert 1)))
```

Outputs:

```
Evaluation took:
  0.007 seconds of real time
  0.005164 seconds of total run time (0.005073 user, 0.000091 system)
  71.43% CPU
  14,060,029 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
```

While running:

```
(time (loop repeat 1000000 do (invert-no-dec 1)))
```

Outputs:

```
Evaluation took:
  0.011 seconds of real time
  0.011327 seconds of total run time (0.011279 user, 0.000048 system)
  100.00% CPU
  25,505,355 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
```

It seems the type declaration makes the function twice as fast. It must be noted that the call to `invert` will probably offset the gain in performance, unless you use `(declaim (inline invert))`. From the [CLHS](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/d_inline.htm):

> inline specifies that it is desirable for the compiler to produce inline calls to the functions named by function-names; that is, the code for a specified function-name should be integrated into the calling routine, appearing ``in line'' in place of a procedure call.

Comment: "the call to `invert` will probably offset the gain in performance" - You can use `(declaim (inline invert))` to inline the call.

Comment: Added! Thank you! :)

Comment: @tsikov: Thank you, logxor was what I was looking for, but missing its significance. Assume now I can do
`(define-modify-macro invertf (&rest args)
  (lambda (bit)
    (declare (type bit bit))
    (logxor bit 1)))`
to take advantage of declarations & inlining?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be working on my machine. (The type declaration is saving CPU, but you cannot inline macros) Just a quick question: why do you want to define a macro to write a place. Why not a simple function? Just curious... :)

Comment: @davypough It would be better to define `INVERT` as a separate (inlined) function instead of using `LAMBDA`. Your `INVERTF` will expand to something like `(setq x ((lambda (bit) (declare (type bit bit)) (logxor bit 1)) x))` in every place where it's used. If you define the modify macro as `(define-modify-macro invertf () invert)`, it'll expand to `(setq x (invert x))`, where the call to `INVERT` can be inlined.

Comment: @tsikov It's likely counterproductive, but I have difficulty "thinking" in the functional programming style (eg, used Scheme for a while). Code seems more perspicuous and concise to me when places are simply modified. I haven't found much difference in debugging, particularly when using lots of declarations and optimizing debug. But I am aware there's a "pure blood" thread in the common-lisp community, based on much more experience than I have, to adhere to certain practices. I wish there was a forum to discuss common-lisp at a more abstract level to better understand the many nuances.

Comment: @jkiiski: Yes, I see the difference now, and it is worth changing my strategy. Thanks.